# Run PSScript with Network share folde

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2012

I have 15 different PS script file's all are store in a `\PSscripts` folder. Inside the script we called another script file `."$PSScriptRoot\ConfigureDatabases.ps1"` this way, `$PSScriptRoot = PSscripts`. I make this variable for script folder.

Now what I want I have 3 different server where respective script need to run from this folder on each server.

If I will share `\PSscripts` folder with all server how can I run script from this folder on respective server.

Comment: The `$PSScriptRoot` is an [automatic variable](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7#psscriptroot) containing the directory from which a script is being run.. Do not try assigning other values to it.

Comment: Put all your function in a .psm1 file (module), place it in a shared location, use Import-Module to load it from whatever host you are using. Use the functions.

Comment: Actually you guys didn't get my question, we have shared drive where other setup also store like Website content API content we can't copy folder to another server,                    what i want we have store all required file and package on shared folder with all server now inside of folder there are 15 script file which need to call during installation,                 now folder is accessing in all server but, script file not able to run, "getting access denied " error

Comment: Walk to each server, log in, open PS, cd to your "PSScripts" folder and run your scripts. This will work for sure ;-) Concerning the "Access denied" error message, you should probably update your question and tell us more about what you are doing.